# Where does the iPhone Simulator store the installed applications?

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator

I want to have a look at the app directory from the iPhone Simulator, so that I can see what kind of files it is creating when I use my app and what stuff is in these files (i.e. when it creates the sqlite file for Core Data and stuff like that).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can find it in

```
~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/User/Applications
```

Comment: Pretty sure this is no longer correct. That folder doesn't exist for me with Xcode Version 9.2 (9C40b).

Answer (score 3):

Each time you build an application a new directory is created in:

```
 ~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/User/Applications
```

If you rebuild your application that application directory is renamed. I usually sort the list by most recent and look at the latest directory in there.

Answer (score 3):

On Lion the users/[username]/library is hidden.

Use

chflags nohidden /users/[username]/library

in a terminal to display the folder.

Answer (score 2):

Since at least Xcode 6.1, my apps are dumped in

```
~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/<hexstring>/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/<hexstring>
```

You can get in your most recently installed app by pasting this into your favorite terminal:

```
cd ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/
cd $(ls -t | head -1)
cd data/Containers/Bundle/Application
cd $(ls -t | head -1)
```